# During add service hdfs in cloudera manager, I am getting error message failed to create tmp directory

Tags: centos7, cloudera

I installed cloudera manager 5.12.0 successfully . But when I try to add hdfs
service, I got following error message :

failed to create tmp directory . But it was installed. Then try to restart cluster. But if failed to start again . It says no data node role are associated with hdfs . At least one node is required.
Could anyone please tell me why I am getting error message like this ? How to solve the problem.

I am using centos 7.

Thanks

Comment: When adding the service, did you assign the DataNode role to some of your servers? It sounds like you just left it empty, which is why it can't start. As the message says: you need at least one DataNode (preferrably at least 3).

Comment: I assigned data node server ( 3 node) . But it was failed.

Comment: What other services/roles did you assign? Did you get any more information to the "Failed to create /tmp directory" message? Can you see anything in the logs located under "/var/log/cloudera-scm-server" or "/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent"?